# Вызов shell команды в Windows c привелегиями администратора (UAC)

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess, uac

Всем привет!

Объясните пожалуйста, что не так и как исправить:

Запускаю следующий код:

```
if not ctypes.windll.shell32.IsUserAnAdmin():
    print(sys.executable, __file__)
    ctypes.windll.shell32.ShellExecuteW(None, 'runas', sys.executable, __file__, None, 1)

try:
    result = subprocess.call(['Dism.exe', '/Online', '/Cleanup-Image', '/CheckHealth'], shell=True)
    print('Код выполнился:', result)
except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
    print('CalledProcessError:', e)
```

После подтверждения административных прав, запускается shell, а в нём Dism.exe, однако, почему-то в python сразу же возвращается код завершения о недостаточных привилегиях. При этом, Dism.exe выполняет свою работу и повышенных прав не требует. Какая-то чёрная магия происходит. Что не так? И как исправить, как сделать так, чтобы не получать ошибку 740 в python от shell?

Comment: А разве через `ctypes.windll.shell32.ShellExecuteW` вы не запустили этот же скрипт с нужными правами и в нем после вызвали `Dism.exe`. Текущий скрипт ведь не получит права. Думаю, если вы выведите результат, например в файл, то будет результат

Comment: Посмотри, пожалуйста, тут: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/130763/r

Comment: @gil9red ааа... вон оно что... т.е, получается у меня два python скрипта работают? Первый не получил права, а второй получил?

Answer (score 1):

Благодаря @gil9red стало ясно, что следующий код в python-скрипте:

```
ctypes.windll.shell32.ShellExecuteW(None, 'runas', sys.executable, __file__, None, 1)
```

запускает внешний WinAPI процесс который параллельно создает другой процесс с этим же python-кодом. Таким образом, в какой-то момент работают 2 скрипта, первый без привилегий завершается, а второй работает с правами администратора.
Решается это строчкой кода, которая завершает первый (родительский) python-процесс:

```
if not ctypes.windll.shell32.IsUserAnAdmin():
    ctypes.windll.shell32.ShellExecuteW(None, 'runas', sys.executable, __file__, None, 1)
    sys.exit() # close current python-process
```

Есть еще вариант вызова команд в subprocess с получением привилегий через **runas**. Как это сделать, ответ [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47380378/run-process-as-admin-with-subprocess-run-in-python).